# A mathematics competition problem: a polynomial in two variables

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

This is a problem in the Final Event of Pui Ching Invitational Mathematics Competition (for high school students) in Hong Kong.

> Let $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ be polynomials in two variables. Suppose $g(0,0)=6$, and that $(x^2+2xy+3y^2)f(x,y)=(4x^2+5xy+6y^2)g(x,y)$ for any real numbers $x$ and $y$ staisfying $x^2y+6y=xy^3+5x^2+2x$. Find the value of $f(0,0)$.

I tried to solve the problem by using limits.
Let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $y\ne0$ and $x^2y+6y=xy^3+5x^2+2x$. Define $\lambda=\frac{x}{y}$. Then $\lambda^2y^3+6y=\lambda y^4+5\lambda^2y^2+2\lambda y$ and $(\lambda^2y^2+2\lambda y^2+3y^2)f(\lambda y,y)=(4\lambda^2 y^2+5\lambda y^2+6y^2)g(\lambda y,y)$. Hence we have $\lambda y^4-\lambda^2y^3+5\lambda^2 y^2+2(\lambda-3)y=0$ and $(\lambda^2+2\lambda +3)f(\lambda y,y)=(4\lambda^2 +5\lambda +6)g(\lambda y,y)$. Let $\displaystyle \lim_{\lambda\to3}y=y_0$. Then $y_0^2(3y_0^2-9y_0+45)=0$ and hence $y_0=0$, as $3y_0^2-9y_0+45>0$ for all real $y_0$. Note that $\displaystyle \lim_{\lambda\to3}(\lambda^2+2\lambda +3)f(\lambda y,y)=18f(0,0)$ and $\displaystyle \displaystyle \lim_{\lambda\to3}(4\lambda^2 +5\lambda +6)g(\lambda y,y)=57g(0,0)$. Therefore, $18f(0,0)=57(6)$ and thus $f(0,0)=19$.

Can anybody give a solution without using limits?

Comment: There is a solution using Hilbert's Nullstellensatz instead of limits, but for a high school competition maybe that's not what you want? btw for your solution to be technically correct, you should show that there exists a sequence of points on the curve with $x/y$ converging to $3$.

Comment: Maybe I spoke too soon, to use Hilbert's Nullstellensatz you'd need to know the property held for complex pairs $(x,y)$ too.

Answer (score 0):

The following is (the outline of) an algebraic solution, though the calculations are rather tedious. Basic idea is to solve the constraint quadratic for $x\,$, substitute back into the relation between $f,g$ then manipulate the resulting expression as to remove the singularity.

As notation, let $\mathcal{Y^k}$ denote an arbitrary polynomial in $y$ containing no powers of $y$ less than $k$. Obviosuly $\mathcal{Y^k}+\mathcal{Y^{k\,'}}=\mathcal{Y^{\min(k,k\,')}}\,$, $\mathcal{Y^k}\cdot\mathcal{Y^{k\,'}}=\mathcal{Y^{k+k\,'}}\,$, and $\mathcal{Y^k} \big|_{y=0}=0$ for $k \ge 1\,$.

The constraint $x^2y+6y=xy^3+5x^2+2x \iff (y-5)x^2-(y^3+2)x+6y=0$ gives:

$$
x = \frac{y^3+2 \pm \sqrt{(y^3+2)^2-24y(y-5)}}{2(y-5)}
$$

The root for which $x=0$ when $y=0$ corresponds to the $-$ minus sign, so:

$$
2(y-5)\,x = y^3+2 - \sqrt{4 + 120y -24 y^2 + \mathcal{Y}^3} = y^3 + 2 - \sqrt{\Delta}
$$

Then:

$$\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
& 4(y-5)^2\,(x^2+2xy+3y^2) \\
 & \;\; = \left(y^3+2\right)^2 - 2 \left(y^3+2\right)\sqrt{\Delta} + \Delta + 4 \left(y^3+2 - \sqrt{\Delta}\right)y(y-5) + 12y^2(y-5)^2 \\[3px]
 & \;\; = 4 - 4 \sqrt{\Delta} + 4 + 120y - 24y^2 + 8y^2 - 40y - 4(y^2-5y)\sqrt{\Delta} + 300y^2 + \mathcal{Y}^3 \\[3px]
 & \;\; = 4\left(2 + 20 y+71y^2 - (1-5y+y^2) \sqrt{\Delta}\right) + \mathcal{Y}^3 \\[5px]
 & \;\; = \frac{4\left(2 + 20 y+71y^2 - (1-5y+y^2) \sqrt{\Delta}\right)\left(2 + 20 y+71y^2 + (1-5y+y^2) \sqrt{\Delta}\right) + \mathcal{Y}^3}{2 + 20 y+71y^2 + (1-5y+y^2) \sqrt{\Delta} + \mathcal{Y}^3} \\[5px]
 & \;\; = \frac{4\left((2 + 20 y+71y^2)^2 - (1-5y+y^2)^2\,(4+120y-24y^2)\right) + \mathcal{Y}^3}{2 + \sqrt{4 + \mathcal{Y}^1} + \mathcal{Y}^1} \\
 & \;\; = \cdots \\
 & \;\; = \frac{7200 y^2 + \mathcal{Y}^3}{2 + \sqrt{4 + \mathcal{Y}^1} + \mathcal{Y}^1} \\[5px] 
 & \;\; =y^2 \,\cdot\, \frac{7200 + \mathcal{Y}^1}{2 + \sqrt{4 + \mathcal{Y}^1} + \mathcal{Y}^1}
\end{align}
$$

Similarly (omitting the detail calculations):

$$
\begin{align}
4(y-5)^2\,(4x^2+5xy+6y^2) & \;=\; \cdots \;=\, y^2\,\cdot\, \frac{182400 + \mathcal{Y}^1}{16+8\sqrt{4 + \mathcal{Y}^1} + \mathcal{Y}^1}\end{align}
$$

It follows that:

$$
f(x,y)= \frac{\cancel{y^2}\,\cdot\, \cfrac{182400 + \mathcal{Y}^1}{16+8\sqrt{4 + \mathcal{Y}^1} + \mathcal{Y}^1}}{\cancel{y^2} \,\cdot\, \cfrac{7200 + \mathcal{Y}^1}{2 + \sqrt{4 + \mathcal{Y}^1} + \mathcal{Y}^1}} \cdot g(x,y)
$$

Thus for $x=y=0\,$:

$$
f(0,0)= \frac{\cfrac{182400}{32}}{\cfrac{7200}{4}} \cdot g(0,0) = \frac{5700}{1800} \cdot 6 = 19
$$